# How does WPF allow named items to be recognized across the entire application?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

When a named XAML element is used in a WPF application, it can be accessed from anywhere.  For example:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid>
        <TreeViewItem Name="itemScreen" />
```

The element `itemScreen` will be directly accessible in `MainWindow()`, although it is several levels deep in the XAML hierarchy.

How does WPF enable this to work in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a mechanism called NameScope.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/wpf-xaml-namescopes

Simple markup you put in a window which has no templating or styling will all have the one namescope.
If you dig through that link it will explain about styles and templates in more detail. Essentially, they have their own namescope.

This is probably as far as you want to go with an explanation at this stage but there are a couple of oddities like when you "inherit" a style using basedon.
I wouldn't worry about them just yet but throw it to the back of your mind for later.

ps
That control is a private member of your window and the name doesn't have to be unique across the entire application.

Comment: Andy, thank you for your detailed answer, much appreciated.